# Default Inline Image Background in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, images

When an image has a transparent background, Emacs of course respects that.

Unfortunately, this can lead to issues with display:

[image: black text on dark background]

Is there a way to display a specific color (e.g. white) behind the image? There appears to be some support for it in [ImageMagick images](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/ImageMagick-Images.html#ImageMagick-Images).

The specific stuff I'm working with right now can have the background color set, however I have to add an extra few lines to *every single figure* in order to do that, which is less than ideal. I would like to get it to where inline images displayed in org-mode have the background color set by default.

(Note: this isn't org-babel specific, it just happens to be how I'm getting these images right now)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much digging, there does *not* appear to be a built-in option to adjust this in Org or in general. The image system does not have any way to customize the default background, and org doesn't have a way to set the `:background` property. However, it does look like most images support the `:background` display property.

I added this functionality to Org by modifying (read: copy and paste into `.emacs.d` with a 1-line change) `org-display-inline-images`.

I won't reproduce the function here, because it is rather lengthy. Line 51 of the function reads:

```
(setq img (save-match-data (create-image file type nil :width width)))
```

I defined a new customizable variable `org-inline-image-background`, which can hold either `nil` (transparent background) or a color:

```
(defcustom org-inline-image-background nil
  "The color used as the default background for inline images.
  When nil, use the default face background."
  :group 'org
  :type '(choice color (const nil)))
```

Then, I added it to line 51:

```
(setq img (save-match-data (create-image file type nil :width width 
                                                       :background org-inline-image-background)))
```

This works beautifully and it can be customized using the color picker, so it satisfies all my requirements.

[image: black text light background]

Comment: Looks like you put in a lot of work to figure this thing out. Would you like to submit a patch for this or request this to be added to org-mode by emailing emacs-orgmode@gnu.org?

Comment: Once I put it through its paces (make sure it doesn't break anything) I'm hoping too.

Comment: The new Org-mode version 8.0 seems start use overlay to display inline images, Is there a way to modify overlay default background color?

Comment: @stardiviner that is exactly what this does

Comment: I checked my Org version, it is `8.3.4`. I checked the `org-display-inline-images` source code, have not found your code definition. Here is the source code: https://gist.github.com/649a7b36031d6adb4a96

Comment: I find the `create-image` line code, then append code as your method. I think this should be an advice. Can you improve your code?

Comment: @stardiviner: no. If you want it as advice, you can use :filter-return (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-combinators.html#Advice-combinators) to do it.

Comment: @JDavidSmith I think this should use `:filter-args` on `create-image` to specify the background color get from the color-theme. But I still can't figure it out how to write this advice.

Answer (score 7):

I got a better solution with advice.

```lisp
(defcustom org-inline-image-background nil
  "The color used as the default background for inline images.
When nil, use the default face background."
  :group 'org
  :type '(choice color (const nil)))

(defun create-image-with-background-color (args)
  "Specify background color of Org-mode inline image through modify `ARGS'."
  (let* ((file (car args))
         (type (cadr args))
         (data-p (caddr args))
         (props (cdddr args)))
    ;; Get this return result style from `create-image'.
    (append (list file type data-p)
            (list :background (or org-inline-image-background (face-background 'default)))
            props)))

(advice-add 'create-image :filter-args
            #'create-image-with-background-color)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Might I suggest renaming the advice function to remove the `org-` prefix since the solution applies much more broadly? With non-default themes, the goal is probably a white background (which is frequently not the default face background), so `(list :background "white")` might be a useful example.

Comment: That is user's option, your consider is right. I think your comment is enough for user who found this code. :)

Comment: Does this still work for you? For me this only seems to work for SVG images with a transparent background, it's not affecting PNG images. I'm using Emacs 29.0.60 on macOS with Org version 9.6.1.