# How do I force SVG figures to appear inline on a white background?

Tags: org-mode, latex, html, inline-image, svg

For nearly three weeks now [EmacsForMacOSX](https://emacsformacosx.com) natively supports viewing SVG figures inline (hurray!).

As expected, and unlike raster images, SVG figures typically have no background.

It is sufficient to set

```
(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)
```

and then the line

```
[[./figure.svg]]
```

in an `org-mode` file will appear inline.

[image: inline SVG image in Emacs]

That's exactly how the SVG figures, whether output to HTML or PDF, will
need to be—since the background will be white.
But while writing (and being rather partial to a dark
Emacs background) I'd like to see the figure on a white background.

How do I force SVG figures to appear inline on a white background?

Also, since <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> `svg` brings up nothing yet, a second(ary) question is worth asking here: how can I set the width of SVG figures in the Emacs frame? (Their width is already consistent and determined by the width of the printed page.)

##### The SVG image above

For reference, here is the SVG image used above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="200" height="150"
    viewBox="0 0 200 150"
    version="1.1">
    <g>
        <path d="M 10 10 L 190 10 L 190 140 L 10 140 z"
            fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
        <circle cx="100" cy="75" r="50"
            fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Such an image meant for a light (white) background will in general be unusable on a dark (black) background, hence the question.

##### Related

This [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37927/28733), which doesn't work for me, attempts to solve the problem through `org-mode`—but in any case the issue is now one of SVG.

Comment: Did you try @stardiviner's solution using `advice`? AFAICT, it should work (IOW, it's not an SVG issue, it's an Emacs `create-image` issue).

Comment: @NickD I did. It didn't work on my side.

Comment: Strange: it worked for me but the image I used already had a light blue background. I'd like to try with a transparent image: can you point me to the one you used?

Comment: Never mind: I changed it with `inkscape`. @stardiviner's [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37927/14825) works fine for me (and is easily reverted too).

Comment: @NickD I added the SVG image.

Comment: @NickD I tried again with a minimal .emacs, and it's still no good. The only modification I made is to replace `  :type '(choice color (const nil)))` with `  :type '(choice color (const white)))`. Is that also what you did on your side?

Comment: No, that does not change the value. I assume you have put the code in a file and you've loaded the file. Do `C-h v org-inline-image-background` and hit `Customize`; click on the value menu and hit `Color`l then click on the choice and click on a color; then hit `Apply`. Now try previewing.

Comment: @NickD Perfect. Your call. Delete the question?

Comment: The question is fine, but it might be a good idea for you to provide an answer summarizing the comments and filling in any gaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/37927/28733) to your `.emacs`, followed by

```
(setq org-inline-image-background "white")
```

Credit for this answer: NickD